# Need to insert text below images in microsoft word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I have A LOT of images in `Microsoft Word` and I need to insert text below each. I have been using:

```
Selection.InsertBefore Text="blah"
```

(along with other code)
But it inserts text to the left of each image

I need to insert text under or above

Comment: add a line break to blah, maybe something like `Selection.InsertBefore Text="blah" & vbNewLine`  ... just a guess.

Comment: inline images, floating images, or both?

Comment: Are these images one below the other, or are some next to each other? If next to each other, what did you use to position them?

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub SomeSub()

    'After inserting the text above the image the text will be selected
    With Selection
        .MoveLeft
        .InsertBefore vbCr
        .InsertBefore "blah"
    End With

    'After inserting the text below the image the text and
    'the paragraph marker next to the image will be selected
    With Selection
        .MoveRight
        .InsertAfter vbCr
        .InsertAfter "blah"
    End With


End Sub
```